# Cities Skylines: Goods vehicles wont use the bypass to the cargo harbour (except ones owned by the cargo harbour??)

Tags: cities-skylines

My city in Cities Skylines is built into some unusual geography, and my main industrial area is on the other side of the city from the cargo harbour, which is on an island. Trucks were all piling onto city streets and then piling into a tunnel to reach the cargo harbour.

I decided to build a direct bypass linking the cargo harbour and the main road at the other side of the city which then leads to the industrial areas. This new bypass not only avoids congested and slow city streets, but it's also geographically direct so I see no reason why people aren't using it.

The strangest thing is that some vehicles are using it... specifically the ones listed as being owned by the cargo harbour. I have checked it many times and I have never seen a single vehicle not owned by the cargo harbour on the bypass, and I've checked and they're going to the same industrial areas as most of the HGVs still going out of their way to use the city streets. It seems the cargo harbour's vehicles avoid the city streets entirely.

The small reduction in traffic with the cargo harbour HGVs avoiding city streets has reduced congestion for now, but it's starting to get worse again so I really need people to start using this bypass.

Any ideas why this is happening and if it's an easy alteration to the road that will fix it? Or if perhaps it's some very obscure glitch?

I have the Traffic Manager Mod, so maybe there's something in that mod which can fix it?
I can't really ban HGVs from any section of road without blocking some other industrial area that actually needs to reach the city centre.

[image]

Comment: Update: The harbour owned vehicles have stopped using it as well. Now nobody is using it. AAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: Update- OK I messed around with some of the road and I seem to have fixed it maybe? No clue what I did but more cars are using it now so I think it's all good. I'll come back to this if problems arise again. Still would be interesting to know why this was happening if anyone happens to know.

Comment: In the vanilla game, once a vehicle selects a route it isn't going to change, unless the original route is broken.  Are you using any mods?